# Bootstrap form disabled beetween 970px width to 751px width

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html

```html
<form action="" id="form">

  <label for="name">NAME:</label>
  <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
  <br>

  <label for="email">E-MAIL:</label>
  <input class="inputfield" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email adress">
  <br>

  <label for="subject">SUBJECT:</label>
  <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
  <br>

  <label for="message">MESSAGE:</label>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="4" class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <br>

  <input class="submitform" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

and it linked to bootstrap. and to another simple css file.

It works good in all the other sizes. I tried some things but nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem with the copy thr <form> open tag is there.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're additional stylesheet is overriding the Bootstrap CSS because of a media query you may have added to it.

Or have you done anything to the Bootstrap CSS itself instead of using a new stylesheet to override it?

Check your stylesheet and if your stylesheet isn't too large you should post it if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately my stylesheet is to large.

Comment: Have you done a  search inside your own stylesheet as far as the media queries go to see if there's any issue with them?

Comment: Yes. The problem was solved, I can't understand the reason but when I remove the col-sm-offset-2 it's fixed the issue.